# Trying to convert .txt into Excel using R, issues with irregular spacing as "delimiter"

Tags: r

I'm a fairly basic user and I'm having issues uploading a .txt file in a neat manner to get a Excel-like table output using R.

My main issue stems from the fact that the "columns" in the .txt file are created by using a varying amount of spaces.  So for example (periods representing spaces, imagining that the info lines up together):

- Mister B Smith....Age 35.....Brooklyn
- Mrs Smith.........Age 33.....Brooklyn
- Child Smith.......Age 8......Brooklyn
- Other Child Smith.Age 1......Brooklyn
- Grandma Smith.....Age 829....Brooklyn

And there are hundreds of thousands of these rows, all with different spaces that line up to make "columns."  Any idea on how I should go about inputting the data?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as your your file is not delimited at all, but in a fixed width format. You focused on the number of spaces when really it seems like the data have varying number of characters in fields of the same fixed width. **You'll need to verify this.** But the first "column" seems to be exactly 19 characters long. Then comes the string `Age` (with a space at the end) and then a 7 character column with the age. Then a final column and it's not clear at all how long it might be.

Of course this could be me overfitting to this small snippet. Check if I have guessed correctly. If I have, you can use the base function `read.fwf` for files like this. Let's say the file name is `foo.txt` and you want to call the result `my_foo`. The `Age` column is redundant, so let's skip it. And let's say the final column actually has 8 characters (the number of characters in `Brooklyn` but you'll need to check this)

```
my_foo <- read.fwf("foo.txt", c(19, -4, 7, 8))
```

might get you what you want. See `?read.fwf` for details.

Comment: So this ended up not working, my example of what it was was super basic, as I can't disclose the information.  Thank you though, this will definitely come in handy later!

Answer (score 0):

If the deliminator is always a number of spaces you can read in your .txt file and split each line into a vector using a regex that looks for more than one space:

```
x <- c("Mister B Smith    Age 35     Brooklyn",
       "Mrs Smith         Age 33     Brooklyn")
stringr::str_split(x, " {2,}")

[[1]]
[1] "Mister B Smith" "Age 35"         "Brooklyn"      

[[2]]
[1] "Mrs Smith" "Age 33"    "Brooklyn"
```

The only problem you might run into with this approach is if, due to the length of one field, there is only one space between fields (for example: `"Mister B Smithees Age 35     Brooklyn"`). In this case, @ngm's approach is the only possible option.